# Xcode NSStatusBar Item not appearing

Tags: swift, nsstatusitem, nsstatusbar

I'm trying to add an item to the status bar, but when I launch the app the item only appears in the top left for a split second and then quickly disappears.

I've looked through the documentation and I can see things have changed recently e.g. `statusItem.title` has become `statusItem.button?.title`. But don't seem to be missing anything else. Any help?

Here's my code:

```
var statusItem : NSStatusItem? = nil

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        // Insert code here to initialize your application

        let statusItem = NSStatusBar.system.statusItem(withLength: NSStatusItem.variableLength)
        statusItem.button?.title = "Connect!"

}
```

Comment: what happens if you remove `let`?

Comment: Doesn't work - says I've got an unresolved identifier...

Answer (score 2):

Ah brilliant. That's worked! Thanks Saleh. After playing around with both our codes, mine seemed to work with the var declaration at the top and without NSMenuDelegate instance. My issue seems to be that I was saying :

let statusItem = NSStatusBar.system.statusItem(withLength: NSStatusItem.variableLength)

All I had to do to make it work was remove the 'let' and just say:

statusItem = NSStatusBar.system.statusItem(withLength: NSStatusItem.variableLength)

Comment: So weird dude! Just by declaring the var outside of appDidFinishLaunching the whole thing worked.

Comment: And that's because statusItem went out of scope at the end of applicationDidFinishLaunching and was automatically cleaned up by the system - thus removing the item from the status bar.

Answer (score 0):

1. AppDelegate should be an instance of *NSMenuDelegate*
2. Define the *statusItem* at creation
3. Setup the button title in the *applicationDidFinishLaunching* callback

   ```
   class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate, NSMenuDelegate {
   let statusItem = NSStatusBar.system.statusItem(withLength:NSStatusItem.variableLength)
   func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
       if let button = statusItem.button {
           //button.image = NSImage(named:NSImage.Name("StatusBarButtonImage"))
           button.title = "connect"
           //button.action = #selector(doSomething(_:))
       }
   }
   ```